# Плавное переключение цвета фона

Tags: javascript

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать плавное переключение цвета фона. Вот сам код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('change-background').onmouseover = function() {
    document.body.style.background = '#400000';
}
document.getElementById('change-background').onmouseout = function() {
    document.body.style.background = '';
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: change-background это id ссылки.

Comment: Вы [это](http://learn.javascript.ru/animation) уже читали? Что не получилось?

Comment: Не получается плавное появление и исчезновение цвета при наведении на пункт меню, прописывал animate, не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел, нужно прописать в css такой код:

```
body {
transition: background-color 1s;
}
html:hover body {
background-color: #400000;
}
```

Вместо `html`, можно указывать любой `class` или `id` того элемента (например блока `div`), на который при наведении хотим поменять фон `body`.
То есть для `javascript` не стоит ни чего менять, а только добавить в `css` найденный ответ.